# Writing a bash script that accepts multiple multi-spaced arguments

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ubuntu

An example from (the excellent) [Unix Programming Environment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013937681X) 
considers an address book:

```
 John Perkins 616-555-4444
 Bill Jotto 773-222-1112
 Dial-a-Clown 738-224-5823
 Prince Alex 837-999-999
 Pizza Hut 833-339-222
 Pizza Puk 882-922-222
 Pizza Buk 822-221-111
```

now I am writing a program that searches this address book called
 '***411***'

```
   grep $* /file/location/411
```

now running 411 will yield

```
 $> 411 John
 >John Perkins 616-555-4444
```

now say I want to call John and invite him for some pizza
(So I am searching for John number and Pizza numbers).

```
 $>411 John Pizza
 grep: can't open pizza
```

No match!

So how to I tell the shell to accept multiple argument with arbitrary spaces?

Comment: When you wrote `$>411 John Perkins Pizza` did you mean `$>411 John Pizza`?  Otherwise both `Perkins` and `Pizza` should have generated errors.

Comment: That's true.. I shall edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `grep` with more than one argument, it assumes the first is the pattern and all others are the files to be searched.  You'll need to make two modifications:

1. When you call your program, you'll need to enclose multi-word arguments in double-quote characters.  This is standard shell behavior.
2. Your program will need to read the arguments from the command line and either send them individually to `grep` or build a compound expression (`arg1|arg2|arg3`) and pass it to `grep` with the `-E` (extended regex) flag.

For example:

```
args="$1"
shift   # $2 becomes $1, $3 becomes $2, and so on
while [ -n "$1" ]; do
   args="$args|$1"
   shift
done

grep -E "$args" /path/to/address/book
```

Or:

```
while [ -n "$1" ]; do
  grep "$1" /path/to/address/book
  shift
done
```

Comment: What if I want an arbitrary number of arguments?

Comment: Cool! The funny thing is the review loops right in the next section and I just didn't make the connection. Thanks a lot.

Comment: "standard linux behavior". You probably mean "standard shell behaviour". Linux doesn't care what shell you use, or how or if that shell processes arguments.

Comment: Shouldn't that be uppercase `-E`, or explicitly call `egrep`?